# How to include the totals field for batchRunReports from GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

In GA3(UA), when making a call to their API batchGet endpoint (https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet), in the response it returns a field containing the total of each metric requested so you don't have to iterate through each row.

I am trying to do the same for GA4 but it doesn't return the total field. Has anyone figured this out before? I checked around and a similar question has popped up but it was language specific, so I couldn't apply it. I am creating the request via Postman.

I have tried looking at the GA4 documentation and in the response object(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/RunReportResponse), it has the totals field and states returned if requested but it does not state how to request this.

[GA4 Response (no totals field)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYe1v.png)

[GA3 Response with totals field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxrZM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to add `TOTAL` the metricAggregations list in your request, see : [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport#:~:text=see%20Pagination.-,metricAggregations,-%5B%5D](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport#:%7E:text=see%20Pagination.-,metricAggregations,-%5B%5D)

Comment: Thank you! It took a while to understand what you meant but I see that it's in the MetricAggregation